# Whether asking questions using rating scores constitutes a likert scale or interval data

Tags: likert

Consider the following item:

3.1 Resources and expertise availability
4 – High availability of resources and expertise
3 – Moderate availability of resources and expertise
2 – Low availability of resources and expertise
1 - No availability of resources and expertise

Respondents have to select one option. Numeric values have been assigned to each option. Can I than use this score data and perform arithmetic operations on it i.e. finding mean, calculating weighted scores etc.

Thank you for your help.